# Evergreen shrub developed large dead area

Tags: diagnosis, shrubs, broad-leaved-evergreens

What would cause this? Do I need to cut out this section? I don’t see any sign of insects. Our area is being infested with the spotted lantern fly.[image]

Comment: Did this just happen or did it come out of the winter looking like this? Are you in a drought right now? Did the dead spot occur slowly or all at once?

Comment: Good question and good overall illustration; if could also include region, and closer illustrations of leaves and branches, and description of onset and time from first appearance to present condition, could be helpful. Thank you. Welcome to the site!

Comment: It has been somewhat dry, however we had over 5 inches of rain in one day from the hurricane last week & the brown area just recently appeared.We are in our 5th heat wave of the summer. We live in suburban area of Philadelphia. When trimmed this shrub has beautiful conical shape.

Comment: I suggest you fight your way into the shrub and see if all the brown growth is coming off one or two main stems or branches arising from the base - if so inspect the stems for any signs of disease, infection or infestation, including at soil level and on the soil, and cut them out at the base. If its more widespread and occurring only in the top parts, then check the backs of affected leaves as well as stems for signs of problems. Any idea what the shrub is? Its not easy to ID, though it might be a Euonymus of some variety, hard to say. Does it flower? If so, when and what colour etc...